# Basic GUI Weight converter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am writing a Weight converter to convert killogram to Pounds and vice versa....
Using QT Desginer I have done the interface etc, but now I am stuck trying to figure out how to link the buttons so that when you press one it converts to pound what is entered and vice versa...

Coding so Far:

```
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(486, 406)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 320, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 60, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(86, 20, 301, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 230, 131, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 230, 111, 21))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 170, 113, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 170, 113, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 441, 311))
        self.label_4.setToolTipDuration(2)
        self.label_4.setText("leh")
        self.label_4.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../../../../Desktop/unbalanced-
    scale.png"))
        self.label_4.setIndent(-4)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_2.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Window"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<<< Pounds to Killogram"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Killogram to Pounds >>>"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               Welcom to PJ Nothnagel\'s Weight Converter!"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "   Killograms"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "  Pounds"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why don't you pear down the interface to something much simpler first to learn how it works, then come back with questions when you have something more specific than *"how do I do it?"*

Comment: For example: create an interface with a single button that has a callback that simply prints "hello world" to the console using `print('hello world')`

Comment: Wish i had time to... the assignment was moved up to tonight....

Comment: If eyllanesc's answer doesn't do it for you I would reccomend using `tkinter` over Qt. It's very well documented, and is imao simpler to understand and get into using.